# mesos masters keep restarting

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos

I have 3 mesos masters with version 0.26.0 setup with a quorum of 2. When I start them, they keep restarting even before I turn up any frameworks or slaves.

Here's the errors I'm seeing:

```
F0322 19:36:56.009903 51459 master.cpp:1368] Recovery failed: Failed to recover registrar: Failed to perform fetch within 1mins

E0322 19:37:18.300568 41095 process.cpp:1911] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 26: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

There's no firewall running.

I start them with supervisord and the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/mesos-master --cluster=int --log_dir=/var/log/mesos/int --quorum=2 --port=5050 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos/work/int --zk=zk://intMesosMaster01:2181,intMesosMaster02:2181,intMesosMaster03:2181/mesos
```

Zookeeper is up and running fine with 3 nodes. It's in use for other projects and has no issues at all with them.

Comment: Also, all the directories are created (/var/log/mesos/int and /tmp/mesos/work/int) and have the correct permissions.   There's also enough free memory for these processes to run.

Comment: Can you make sure that masters have access to the ZooKeeper? Also, could you please clean up the master work dir (`/tmp/mesos/work/int` in your case) and try again?

Comment: ZK is running on those same 3 servers as mesos masters. And since iptables is disabled, there's no issues of connectivity.   the work_dir has been cleaned up as well.  The issue still persists.

Comment: Are you sure ZK builds up a cluster itself? What't the log output?

Comment: yes. the same zk cluster is being used by a kafka server.

Comment: There's no errors in the zk log. zk is working fine. Just this:  Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf-int/zoo.cfg
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default

Comment: When mesos-master crashes and supervisor restart it, I see this in the ZK log: `2016-03-23 13:57:22,035 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@357] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1539fcf0658000d, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:230)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: So if I just start one of the nodes up with --quorum=1 , it stays up and running. But the moment I start up any of the other nodes they all start crashing.

Comment: The only way to get them up and running was to change the quorum to 1 for all 3 nodes.